# Running 2 cypher queries for full text search returns error in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a task in hand where for an input job title pairs I have to output how similar these 2 titles are. For similarity I will be taking into account different factors like common relationships between 2 job title nodes etc.

I am currently into the 1st part, i.e getting a best matching job title node for input job title. I am using the full-text-search capability of neo4j to solve this. I have come up with the following query

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes("full-text-job-title", '"software engineer" OR (software~0.7 engineer~0.7)') yield node, score
with collect(node)[..1] as matchedTitles1
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes("full-text-job-title", '"software developer" OR (software~0.7 developer~0.7)') yield node, score
with collect(node)[..1] as matchedTitles2
return matchedTitles1[0], matchedTitles2[0]
```

It returns the following error

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Variable `matchedTitles1` not defined (line 5, column 8 (offset: 351))
"return matchedTitles1[0], matchedTitles2[0]"
        ^
```

I am unable to solve this error. Also I want to return the `top matching job-title node` for each of the input job title pair. Currently I have come up with this - `with collect(node)[..1] as matchedTitles1`, but I think there has to be a better way to return the `top matching job-title node`

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: I've answered why you've got a syntax error and how to fix it, but the second question is too vague for me to help with. I'd probably create a new post dedicated to it with some expected input and output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax error is because you're not passing through `matchedTitles1` in your second `WITH` statement. Everything from before the `WITH` that you want to refer to after the `WITH` needs to be included in the `WITH` statement.

The following is valid Cypher:

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes("full-text-job-title", '"software engineer" OR (software~0.7 engineer~0.7)') yield node, score
with collect(node)[..1] as matchedTitles1
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes("full-text-job-title", '"software developer" OR (software~0.7 developer~0.7)') yield node, score
with collect(node)[..1] as matchedTitles2, matchedTitles1 // Pass through matchedTitles1 from the first CALL so it's visible in the RETURN
return matchedTitles1[0], matchedTitles2[0]
```